# Limit as r tends towards the radial center of a spherical quantum well

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations, limits-without-lhopital, bessel-functions, spherical-harmonics

Suppose $$R\left ( r \right )=\frac{u\left ( r \right )}{r}$$

Where $$u\left ( r \right )=A\sin\left ( kr \right )+B\cos\left ( kr \right )$$

The boundary condition is $$u\left ( a \right )=0 \wedge |u\left ( 0 \right )|< \infty$$

Indeed, putting the equation in order, we have

$$R\left ( r \right )=\frac{u\left ( r \right )}{r}=\frac{A\sin\left ( kr \right )}{r}+\frac{B\cos\left ( kr \right )}{r}$$

For the boundary condition to hold, we require that B=0 to prevent a blow up of the reciprocal 1 on 0-fair enough

But happens to $$\frac{A\sin\left ( kr \right )}{r}$$ as r tends to zero?

Clearly, the result is indeterminate. How does one get around explaining away the fact that it is alright that is not an issue-physical or mathematical.

Comment: The singularity is removable since $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{A\sin(kr)}{r}=Ak$.  So, we simply let $R$ be given by $$R(r)=\begin{cases}AK&,r=0\\\\A\frac{\sin(kr)}{r}&,r>0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Dr.MV That is with the use of Hopital rule. Is there a way to justify the finite limit without the use of that rule?

Comment: Yes.  Recall that $|x\cos (x)|\le |\sin(x)|\le |x|$ for $|x|\le \pi/2$.  Then, use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: or you can consider the Maclarin series for sin.